# CSS Vertically Align List items in a div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a Div bar with a white background in which my breadcrumb lives.

Here you can see a screenshot:

[image]

How can i align the text vertically?

Here is my **CSS**:

```css
/*  Breadcrumb  */
#breadcrumb {
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    behavior: url(/scripts/PIE.htc);
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #526472;
}
#breadcrumb ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#breadcrumb li {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
#breadcrumb a {
    padding-right: 10px;
    background: url(../images/div_breadcrumb.gif) no-repeat right center;
    color: #526472;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

And my **HTML**:

```
<div id="breadcrumb" class="clearfix">
    <ul>
        <li style="white-space: nowrap;"> 
            <a style="white-space: nowrap;" href="">Home</a> 
        </li>
        <li style="white-space: nowrap;"> 
            Visual collaboration solutions 
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="shareThis" class="fl_right"> Share: </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just add width to #breadcrumb and ul style .

Comment: Sorry typo..I meant vertically align

Comment: so just delete float:left of your li style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to incomplete code, it's a bit hard to tell, but I'm guessing that you're either missing some markup, or that there are other styles messing with your breadcrumbs.

The following works just fine to display items in a horizontal row (your styles, my HTML).

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #breadcrumb         { position: relative; background: white; padding: 4px; border-radius:2px; -moz-border-radius: 2px;  -webkit-border-radius: 2px; behavior: url(/scripts/PIE.htc); font-size: .9em; color: #526472;}
        #breadcrumb ul      { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;  }
        #breadcrumb li      { float: left; padding-left: 25px;}
        #breadcrumb a       { padding-right: 10px; background: url(../images/div_breadcrumb.gif) no-repeat right center; color: #526472; margin-right: 5px;}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="breadcrumb" class="clearfix">
         <ul>
             <li>Home Visual collaboration solutions</li>
             <li>La</li>
             <li>Ti</li>
             <li>Da</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are using ul and li tags properly, you might try using Firebug or the Chrome developer tools to detect whether or not other styles are being applied.

Comment: Hey I added the html to original post but cant get it show some reason

Comment: I also want it the entire UL Aligned Centered in the div

Comment: i helped you to format better the question and the code. @StevieB

Comment: Thanks man I also added an image, you can see the breadcrumb is not quite centered in the white div

Comment: I made a type I meant vertically aligned

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
li{display: inline}
```

You could also use

```
li{display:inline-block}
```

That way your `li` elements wont lose their block properties

Here's the example :

http://jsfiddle.net/bFe35/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your **CSS** file, by adding `vertical-align:middle;` to your `#breadcrumb` ID, like this:

```
#breadcrumb {
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    behavior: url(/scripts/PIE.htc);
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #526472;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```